# Redmine: associated revisions not updating for non-master branches

Tags: git, branch, redmine, revision

I have redmine configured with a git repository.  The repository updates properly, and I can browse through all repository branches in redmine with no problem.  However, associated revisions don't show up in issues automatically for commits made to any branch other than master.

If I jump to the repository tab and browse the branch in question, I can see my most recent commits, and only after this step are the associated revisions listed under the issues they refer to.

How do I make associated revisions update automatically, regardless of which branch my changes are committed to?

Answer (score 2):

Generally, there are three ways to load commits into Redmine:

- By loading the Repository tab, as you did for the branch.
- By using Git hook, which seems to be used for master.
- By using cron task, which also can be used for master in your case.

I guess, the script, which runs for the post-commit hook or under cron, checks if it's master and then updates Redmine. So, you need to check this script.

See also:

- [About Git hooks](http://git-scm.com/book/ch7-3.html)
- [Abount configuring update of repository change sets](http://projects.andriylesyuk.com/projects/mastering-redmine/sample-chapter#29)